# How do I call a completion block from SwiftUI view using a search bar?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I would like to make a search bar in this view but I am wondering how I go about calling my completion block which fills the data. At the moment I have the completion block in `.onAppear` but when I go to add a search bar, the data will only be loaded once in `.onAppear` and so when I search, the results won't update. Here is my view

```
struct CocktailList: View {
    @State private var cocktails: [Cocktail]
    @State private var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                List(cocktails, id: \.idDrink) { cocktail in
                    NavigationLink(destination: CocktailDetail(fromCocktail: cocktail)) {
                        CocktailRow(fromCocktail: cocktail)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Search Results")
            }.onAppear {
                requestCocktail(searchTerm: "daiquiri") { cocktails in
                    self.cocktails = cocktails
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        self.cocktails = []
    }
}
```

How do I call `requestCocktail()` upon the update of the searchText and what is the best way to integrate a simple search bar?

Comment: show us the code for your search bar, or what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave you an example with a TextField and different related actions: `onCommit`, `onEditing`, when the text changes, when the text hasn't changed for 1 second. It's up to you to choose when you want to execute `requestCocktail()`.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI
struct SwiftUIView11: View {
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var result: String = ""
    let textHasChanged = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    let debouncer: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>

    init() {
        debouncer = textHasChanged
            .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(result)

            TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: {
                isEditing in
                result = isEditing ? "isEditing" : "isNotEditing"
            }, onCommit: {
                result = "onCommit"
            })
                .background(Color.yellow)
            .onChange(of: text) { newText in
                result = "text changed : \(newText)"
                textHasChanged.send()
            }
            .onReceive(debouncer) { _ in
                result = "paused editing"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a clear separation of concerns in mind:

(Prerequisite: iOS 15)

1. Your Cocktail View

```
struct CocktailsView: View {
    let items: [String]
    @Binding var query: String

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) { string in
                Text(verbatim: string)
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $query, prompt: "enter query")
    }
}
```

It displays your items and provides a "search bar".

Note, that it does not change its view state and that is uses a *binding* for the query string to communicate it with its parent view.

I also omitted some details from the original, since it is not relevant to the question.

2. Provide a View Model:

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    // Defines the _what_ to render in the View
    struct ViewState {
        var query: String = ""
        var items: [String] = []
    }

    // A set of Inputs
    enum Event {
        case query(String)
    }

    private let input = PassthroughSubject<Event, Never>()
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable!

    @Published private(set) var viewState: ViewState = .init()


    init() {
        // Sets up a system of pipes, loosely resembling a 
        // FSM with extended state but no outputs:
        cancellable = input
            .prepend(.query(""))
            .map { event in
                return self.update(state: self.viewState, event: event)
            }
            .sink(receiveValue: { newState in
                self.viewState = newState
            })
    }

    // We don't want to expose the PassthroughSubject to the 
    // view, so define a convenience function that hides 
    // the details for Views:
    func send(_ event: Event) {
        input.send(event)
    }

    // Combines the _transition_ an the _output_ function 
    // of the FSM. It's pretty easy in this use case.
    private func update(state: ViewState, event: Event) -> ViewState {
        let newState: ViewState
        switch (self.viewState, event) {
        case (_, .query(let query)) where query.isEmpty:
            newState = .init(query: "", items: self.items)
        case (_, .query(let query)):
            let query = query.lowercased()
            newState = .init(query: query,
                             items: self.items.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(query) } )
        }
        print("update(\(state), \(event) -> \(newState)" )
        return newState
    }

    private let items: [String] =
        "quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget"
        .split(separator: " ")
        .map { String($0) }

}
```

Here, the View Model is "event driven" and uses Combine under the hood. It also resembles a "extended finite state machine" where "input" are the inputs of the FSM. But, really, the is pretty irrelevant - it's an implementation detail - and just an example how you can implement a view model.

With an FSS you need an `update` function. It is a *pure* function solely responsible to generate a new View State from the current view state and the event.

3. Use a Content View which puts the things together:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        let binding: Binding<String> = .init {
            viewModel.viewState.query
        } set: { query in
            viewModel.send(.query(query))
        }

        NavigationView {
            CocktailsView(
                items: viewModel.viewState.items,
                query: binding)
            .navigationTitle("Results")
        }
    }
}
```